# Is there a way to add the Docker host to a container's /etc/hosts using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**TL;DR** Is there a simple method for assigning the docker host address to a hostname in a docker-compose container?

I'm using selenium hub for testing, running in a Docker container. On my dev machine, I can see my web application at `http://localhost:8080` but in the context of the selenium hub, `localhost` is not available. What I'd like to do is write my tests so that I can use a URL like `http://dockerhost:8080/` to test the application.

The wrinkle is that the development of this code takes place on multiple machines, some of which are on different networks, in different locations, etc. So I'd like to do this in a way that doesn't involve modifying the `docker-compose.yml` file for each host where it might be run.

I have the selenium hub and browser images in a separate docker-compose.yml file from my application, which looks something like this:

```
hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
        - 4444:4444
    extra_hosts:
        dockerhost: 1.2.3.4

firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    links:
        - hub
    extra_hosts:
        dockerhost: 1.2.3.4

chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    links:
        - hub
    extra_hosts:
        dockerhost: 1.2.3.4
```

This works, but requires the `docker-compose.yml` file to be updated with IP addresses on each host. Given that the `docker-compose.yml` file is committed to the `git` repository for the project, this is not acceptable.

What I'd like to do would be replace those hard-coded IP addresses with something (an environment variable? some special `docker-compose` value?) that will use the correct IP address when `docker-compose up` is executed. I've seen a number of different questions here asking similar questions, but not quite the same and I've tried a number of different approaches.

I've tried replacing `1.2.3.4` with an environment variable, DOCKER_HOST, and running it like this:

```
# in the docker-compose.yml file
extra_hosts:
    dockerhost: $DOCKER_HOST

# run docker-compose up on the command line
DOCKER_HOST=1.2.3.4 docker-compose up
```

and it works. But that's one more thing to remember when starting the containers - I've already left it out once. I've also tried replacing the environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml` file with a bash command to extract the IP address like this:

```
extra_hosts:
    dockerhost: $(ip -4 addr show eth0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')
```

but this, perhaps unsurprisingly, does not work.

Any other ideas?

Comment: i think its because it can only interpolate variable not shell commands..

Comment: Does the application you want to test run as a Docker container itself or purely on the Docker host?